# Logical reason why this creature saves its digested victims consciousness?

Tags: internal-consistency, xenobiology

So, there is a monstrous creature called the Tayan. It was created many thousand years ago by a hyper advanced race that created it as a sort of biological torture mechanism.

It’s so huge it can swallow a weight class 7B creature (human sized) whole, and digest it without breaking a sweat. If you go down into the main digestion stomach, you will most likely be killed in about 5 years, after much pain and agony.

But some victims are sent to the secondary stomach, were they are paralyzed by neurotoxins and kept in pain for up to 30 years, until the Tayan needs extra energy during spore season. But, unknown to most of the Tayan’s victims, a worse fate soon awaits those in the belly of the beast.

While a victim lays paralyzed in the Tayans stomach, the creature slowly leeches away a creatures “neural energy” the energy that contains intelligent creatures memories, thoughts, and personalities. After the leeching is finished, the victim and Tayan become one, and the victims consciousness becomes essentially immortal, living out the rest of the Tayan’s 10,000 year lifetime. The entire ‘leeching’ process takes a lot of energy, from start to finish, so my question is what is a logical reason why a Tayan would save a victims consciousness?

-The Tayan is an Animal, but it can also photosynthesize.

Comment: Once more, look up [Sarlacc](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sarlacc). As regards the consciousness, it needs "neural energy" to breed, i.e., locate mates and propagate its genetic material. Since it's not too bright, it needs additional  "neural energy".

Comment: A man cannot survive more than a few days without drinking and eating, no more than few minutes without breathing. Unless this thing's stomach is a fully furnished apartment, there is no way this can happen

Comment: @L.Dutch: No. The creature sticks a tentacle in its victims mouth and nostrils, and provides all the necessary nutrients.

Comment: Spending 100\$ to maintain something worth 1\$ is not logic. Feeding a man 30 years while the amount of energy that can be gained from its digestion is way less is similarly not logic at all.

Comment: @L.Dutch: The Creature gets 90% of its energy form photosynthesis. Eating people is just for torture not real filling nourishment. Before the genetic engineering, the Tayan was just a regular carnivorous plant.

Comment: @L.Dutch: How is the creatures digestive system inefficient

Comment: Eating something today and digesting it in 30 years while keeping it alive is not digestion, is voluntary assumption of a parasite.

Comment: @L.Dutch: How. The ‘parasite’ gets little gain

Comment: It seems to me this is a bit like misery porn applied to creature design.

Comment: @Liquid: What do you mean?

Comment: I meant that it's simply too much. You want a giant carnivore plant, able to ingest humans, store them for years in agonizing pain while AT THE SAME TIME keeping them alive so they can still feel pain, wasting energies to keep their food reserve alive and awaken, and on top of that, it also cannibalizes their mind? It's simply too much. It feels to me like an overpowered adversary made to provoke incredible dread into your audience. The point is, at least some of your audience will see through this. You risk it becoming alienated with your novel/your media because you're overdoing it.

Comment: @Liquid: Ok, so what’s a better idea? It’s suppo to be a biological torture chamber, why wouldn’t it be over the top? Give suggestions?

Comment: @RobertPaul because with being so over the top you're making it unbelievable. And since drama comes from meaningful conflict, you're lessening the value of the conflict it should create. Either make it less powerful and less complex (make it digest people right away, forget the mind-assimilating thing) or divide its powers over to smaller creatures. For example, the consciousness of the previous victims could pass over to a species of internal parasites of the Tayan, to be eventually excreted out.

Comment: Then again those are just my feelings about the idea, I realize I'm not being exactly helpful to the scope of the questions. Feel free to disregard this.

Comment: @L.Dutch: How is this creatures digestive system unrealistic?

Comment: See my comments above: too much effort for too low gain. Add also what @Liquid stated.

Comment: Let's put some facts on the table, folks. Is this realistic?  Not in any sense of the word, but neither is, what, 80% of what we deal with on this site? A lot of the previous conversation appears to be an unwanted and unecessary effort to convince the OP that his question is without merit, as if it didn't deserve to be asked here. Nonsense! I'm going to beat on @Liquid the hardest (no offense), but your complaint is entirely subjective.  The critter was desgined for a purpose, and you're complaining that the purpose is unnatural.  My response: exactly!  Honestly, if you don't like it, move on.

Comment: @JBH Nah, the question has merit, and I do realize I did almost nothing to answer it: I've already stated that. Yet, as Robert has all rights to design his creatures the way he subjectively likes them, one has all the rights to raise doubts (subjective as it may be). I could argue that there could be value in a subjective critique ...but then again, I'll stop cluttering this questions with my comments. (No offense taken, btw)

Comment: @Liquid, cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I feel like the answer to this one is already in the question.

> It was created many thousand years ago by a hyper advanced race that created it as a sort of biological torture mechanism.

You're correct that in evolutionary terms, such an expensive digestion system makes no sense. But since we're dealing with a creature that was genetically-engineered by Sufficiently-Advanced Aliens for the sole purpose of torturing people, that kinda goes out the window.

So the retention of its victims' souls is just another part of the torture. You've endured years of agony being slowly digested in its stomach, you think you've finally been put out of your misery... but now you're part of it, helpless to do anything but watch as others suffer the same fate as you did, over and over again for thousands of years. I dunno about you, but that sounds pretty horrifying to me.

Comment: Souls can’t feel physical pain though.

Comment: They can probably feel psychological or emotional pain, though. There's more than one kind of torture.

Comment: Im still having a little trouble getting it. Where does the physcological pain come in?

Comment: Where does the physiological and emotional pain come form. I don’t understand

Comment: Why would that be physiological torture. Also, why is the Tayan digestive system unrealistic

Comment: Hey, I still don’t get it

Comment: F1Krazy implies that being still able to retain their consciousness, the Tayan's victims would still mourn their deaths after the event, living the centuries to come in distress. Or at least I think.

Comment: @Liquid: Yeah, but they get to live for almost 10,000 years (give or take). Wouldn’t most welcome this near immortality

Comment: Yes, but (I assume) they wouldn't have control over a body, and probably they couldn't interact with each other or the environment; so they would live an extremely long life as spectators of a monster.

Comment: @Liquid: But I still don’t get it. You basically just become one with the monster, hang out for ~10,000 years, and watch the occasionally exciting execution topside. Not that torturous?

Comment: @RobertPaul I don't know, your guess is as good as mine on that. I still wouldn't want that kind of immortality.

Comment: @Liquid: Why not?

Comment: @RobertPaul I wouldn't like living in the body of the monster who ingested me (body of which I have no control). We don't have much experience of what it means for a sentient human to be trapped in a body (there are few cases of siamese twins with limited control, I guess) and also a great deal of psychological pressure is to be expected (imagine the eternity and no one to talk to. And nothing to do). But then again you're free to think otherwise.

Comment: @Liquid: Oh, I finally just got it. Isolation and loneliness would be pretty torturous. I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

**Developer motto:  Use Old Code.**

Old code is good.  It is already there.  It is road tested.  It saves you a lot of work.  Use it if you can.

So it was with the Tayan.  This consciousness saving thing is an artifact of the previous build, because its developers built the Tayan on the platform of an older (and very successful) structure of an organic device intended to preserve consciousnesses for later communication and possible reconstitution back to a physical body.

The developers of the Tayan were engineers and coders under pressure from their evil overlords who wanted a torture device, fast.  The developers did not bother to bypass, delete or otherwise inactivate the old routines built into the framework they used as a basis.  So the Tayan still does all that stuff.  The overlords did not care and possibly did not know; they were satisfied by the torture aspects.

The developers also saw a very real possibility that they themselves or people they cared about might be fed to the Tayan.  Maybe they felt guilt in making a machine with such an evil purpose.   The consciousness preserving system, back when in use, was routinely used on the dying or those at great risk to die, so that they might be restored to a new body later.  By leaving those routines incorporated into the Tayan, the developers saw a chance to save those who were fed to it, in hopes of later rescue and reconstitution when the evil overlords fell out of power.

Comment: If the whole process is so slow, could be a bug(TM). Since they tested it a few weeks and called it *Good enough*. After the first creature reached 30 years mark and started showing weird behaviour, the designers were no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

**The last thing its creators wanted was for it to protest its creation**

The creators had no desire for an *intelligent* creature.  Heavens, no!  What if it decided that life stank and rationalized turning on its creators?  Worse, what if it decided that it should draw a welfare check and watch *I Love Lucy* reruns rather than do its job?  Oh, my... *What if it never left home!*

Nononononono....

**But they do really hate their enemies...**

What the creators did want, however, was for the creature to fully understand how to create the most pain possible.  It's not enough that the body slowly boil and melt over decades of digestion.  The creators wanted <s>their</s> its victims to *truly suffer.*  We don't simply want them to live through every moment there's a nerve to be simulated... we want them to be *concious and sane* while it happens!

So, the micro-tentacles that invade the brain don't just suck nural energy away, they actually manipulate memory while doing so.  Are you afraid of spiders?  Heh, heh... meet your worst nightmare!  But don't forget that "sane" part.  We want you terrorized of spiders, but we don't want you to become a gelatenous vegetable due to over shock.

So, one aspect of the Tayan's creation is that it can store away useful facts about torture.  Was one guy really terrified by spiders?  That's useful information!  It gets stored and used again.  Those memories (like any memory) that are used frequently are remembered longer.  Those that don't slowly fade into forgetfulness.

But another aspect is how to deal with feedback concerning the state of the mind.  It understands what conciousness and sanity are and is constantly seeking to keep both at high, active levels.  Oh, yes... those devilish creators... they wanted you to really feel every possible second of your ordeal.

Because they *really* hate your guts....

But, to do any of this, the Tayan must leech that lovely neural energy.

**TL;DR**

The creature needs the neural energy because it has the ability to:

- Understand the mind of its victim
- Use that understanding to maximize fear and pain
- Use that understanding to force the victim to remain conscious
- Use that understanding to force the victim to remain sane

However, I propose...

- The stored information can only be used for the creature's purpose
- It cannot be used to serve its own self
- It will not become more sentient, intelligent, or capable because of it

Otherwise you'd have creatures that become more godlike with every absorbed consciousness and you eventually have a creature that can modify its own purpose, making it very dangerous to its own creators.  That would go against what I believe would be the creator's natural intent.

Comment: I don’t want to sound like an idiot, but can you give a simplified version of your answer. It’s a little difficult to “digest”. Get the pun, lol

Answer (score 0):

**Tayan was a prototype afterlife(hell) machine**

The engineers who created Tayan were looking to create a machine that could store the consciousness of dying **convicted** members of society in a sort of custom generated after-life hell. This would both serve as a guaranteed hell as well as allow loved ones to commune with their incarcerated loved ones at will. While also serving as a deterrent.

The stomachs acted as a life support and preparatory process to aid the slow neural transfer of convicted patients to the hive mind. However Tayan was  developed for the physiology of the now deceased race.

After transfer was complete the bodies would be absorbed (as food) by Tayan to further reinforce his purpose as a graveyard. (its like the ultimate gravestone)

**Fast Forward to the present**

Since Tayan was developed to ultimately absorb consciousness of A Species, he can still be trying (mindlessly)to accomplish that with the new species only has trouble figuring it out so he takes awhile to **hack** them in. And since its a **hack** in they may not enjoy the amenities of their new afterlife as it wasn't designed for their minds.

**Edit:**
switched the posed argument from a artificial heaven to an artificial hell for convicts.

Comment: But the Tayan was designed to always cause agonizing pain. Why would they put that in an afterlife machine

Comment: Well I missed that part, I figured the ancients weren't around to explain why they made such a monster.

Comment: @RobertPaul there now It is an artificial hell instead of an artificial heaven. The ancients were the ultimate atheists and loved their law.

Answer (score 0):

**SO THAT THERE IS A RECORD OF TORTURE SESSIONS**

The Progenitors want the Tayan to keep a really detailed record of torture sessions. As a result, it has been designed to not only maintain its own memory of each session and not forget even the tiniest element of it but also to acquire the memories of its victims so that the Progenitors can review the torture session from the victim's perspective instead of just the Tayan's.

In essence, the Tayan ISN'T saving the victim's consciousness, it's saving the victim's memories so that it's creators can review them whenever they wish.